# Dropdown to Enum

Tags: c#, enums, drop-down-menu

I want to cast the string output of the selected value from dropdown to an enum.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What language/framework are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap this into an extension method to make the call easier:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value) {

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot convert null or empty string to an enum");
    }

    // Get enum from the built-in Parse method
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);

}
```

Then call

```
myValue.ToEnum<EnumNameHere>();
```

To get the enum

Comment: Hi,
This worked for me:

n1.n2.n3.enum = (n1.n2.n3.enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(n4.n5.n6.enum),stringval)

where n1..6 are name spaces where respective enums are defined.
Thanks for evryone's help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about C# (just a guess) ->

`Enum.Parse(...)`

***EDIT:***
Here are the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

Comment: I tried Enum.Parse(((System.Type)n1.n2.n3.enum1), stringval,true);  but gives error that enum1 is a type not valid in current context and where n1.n2.n3 is the namespace where public enum enum1 is declared.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing strings in the dropdown, than you can also use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) block. Have you considered populated the dropdown with the enum values? See here [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).